# MinGW determines that I don't have a valid gcc compiler

Tags: git, bash, gcc, mingw, configure

When I try to compile from source with MinGW with `./configure` and `make`, the configure command throws an error that says I don't have a working GCC compiler installed.

[image: Git Bash output]

Pastebin for `config.log`: https://pastebin.com/6xYJz0uK

However, I do have `mingw32-gcc` installed.

[image]

Maybe I've done something stupid, or it could be a faulty installation of MinGW/GCC.

EDIT: I have tried reinstalling MinGW and GCC but that did not work too.

Comment: Check that you can type `gcc` at the commandline there (instead of `./configure`) and it works

Comment: Also do the "see config.log for details"

Comment: @M.M I just tried compiling a sample C file called `helloworld.c` with `gcc` and it compiled it to `a.out` without any errors or output. EDIT: this was on my Linux machine, here the `./configure` command just works. I am now trying to compile on Windows MinGW.

Comment: @M.M And `gcc` compiles my `helloworld.c` file too. See this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/bWYyP

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your config log: Use `/` for directory delimiters instead of `\`. The current `\`-es are "eaten":

```
configure:5214: gcc -m64 D:\Documenten\mpir-3.0.0 conftest.c >&5
gcc.exe: error: D:Documentenmpir-3.0.0: No such file or directory
```

Apart from that the error is caused by a faulty `CPPFLAGS`, it does not make any sense at all, just `unset CPPFLAGS` and you should be fine.

Comment: I removed CPPFLAGS from my Environment Variables but with no luck. These two suspicious errors just came up in my `config.log`: `d:/programma's/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied` and `./configure: line 4997: cc: command not found`.

Comment: There is no `a.exe` in you pastebin. Perhaps there already is one and you are not allowed to overwrite it ? `cc` should not be used, it should have detected `gcc` is working, but that probably has to do with the other error.

Comment: Sorry for all confusion, I solved it by using the native Windows 10 Bash implementation and it worked out very well. Thanks for your help!